# $g,h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ measurable and $X$, $Y$ independent => $g(X)$, $h(Y)$ independent?

Tags: measure-theory, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent and integrable random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathfrak F, \mathbb P)$ with probability density functions $f_X$ and $f_Y$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

1) Why does it follow, that $X^2$ and $\sqrt |Y|$ are also independent?

2) Let's say that $g,h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are measurable and $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Does this already imply, that $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are also independent? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2) is right. To see this, simply observe that $P(g(X)\in A,h(Y)\in B)=P(X\in g^{-1}(A),Y\in h^{-1}(B))=P(X\in g^{-1}(A))P(Y\in h^{-1}(B))=P(g(X)\in A)P(h(Y)\in B)$$

Here of course $A$ and $B$ are Borel sets

Answer (score 2):

Any event of form $[X^2 \in A]$ is also an event of form $[X\in A']$ for some $A'$. And so on...